# Cannot delete json element

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a node js function:

```
function func() {
  USER.find({},function(err, users){
    user = users[0];

    console.log(user); // {"name":"mike", "age":15, "job":"engineer"}
    user.name = "bob"; //{"name":"bob", "age":15, "job":"engineer"}
    delete user.name;
    console.log(user); // {"name":"mike", "age":15, "job":"engineer"} name still there??
  });
}
```

Here USER is a mongoose data model and find is to query the mongodb. The callback provide an array of user if not err. The user data model looks like

`{"name":"mike", "age":15, "job":"engineer"}`.

So the callback is invoked and passed in users, I get the first user and trying to delete the "name" from user. The wired part is I can access the value correctly and modify the value. But if I 'delete user.name', this element is not deleted from json object user. Why is that?

Comment: do also `console.log(delete user.name)`, it should return `true`, otherwise, it couldn't be deleted for somehow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the best workaround, but... have you tried setting to `undefined`?

```
user.name = undefined;
```

Comment: Good suggestion, it worked. But why 'delete' doesn't work?

Comment: @MattSun [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342558/why-cant-i-delete-a-mongoose-models-object-properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342558/why-cant-i-delete-a-mongoose-models-object-properties) may be helpful.

Comment: maybe reading this helps http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/ I was trying to find why, by reading that

Answer (score 8):

As others have said, this is due to mongoose not giving you a plain object, but something enriched with things like `save` and `modifiedPaths`.

If you don't plan to save the user object later, you can also ask for lean document (plain js object, no mongoose stuff):

```
User.findOne({})
.lean()
.exec(function(err, user) {

  delete user.name; // works
});
```

Alternatively, if you just want to fetch the user and pay it forward without some properties, you can also use`select`, and maybe even combine it with `lean`:

```
User.findOne({})
.lean()
.select('email firstname')
.exec(function(err, user) {

  console.log(user.name); // undefined
});
```

Comment: nice details on alternatives. Thanks.