# delete object.property does not work with Mongoose Created Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am using Mongoose to create a user model in the database. When I return the user model to the browser, I would like to remove certain fields such as Salt and Password Hash.

I am using the Javascript delete keyword, but it is not deleting these properties.

I have written two examples.

**Example 1 (Works): Create User Object with Salt, delete salt**

```
describe('Manual User Object', function () {

  it('should delete salt', function (done) {

    // MANUALLY CREATE JAVASCRIPT OBJECT
    var entity = { name: 'david', 'salt': 'yes please' };

    l.kv('typeof entity', typeof entity);
    l.kv('typeof entity.salt', typeof entity.salt);

    l.line('before delete');
    l.inspect(entity);
    l.info();

    l.line('delete entity.salt');
    var isDeleted = delete entity.salt;
    l.kv('Is Successful', isDeleted );
    l.info();

    l.line('after delete');
    l.inspect(entity);

  });

});
```

**Example 2 (NOT Working): User Object created in Mongoose with Salt**

**Create User Controller Function**

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------
// CREATE: Creates a new user in the DB.
// ------------------------------------------------------------
exports.create = function (req, res) {

  //var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
  //console.log(fullUrl);

  try {

    UserSchema.create(req.body.entity, function (err, entity) {

      if (err) {
        return mong.handleError(res, err);
      }

      // Fails to remove Salt
      entity = santitise(entity);

      return res.status(201).json(mong.formatSuccess(entity));
    });

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

**Failing Unit Test**
  it('should create an ' + modelName, function (done) {

```
var payload = td.users.newEntity('David', 'david@test.com', 'orderer', 'password');

request(app)
    .post('/api/users')
    .send(mong.wrapEntity(payload))
    .expect(201)
    .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
    .end(function (err, res) {

      if (err) {
        l.logTheUnknown(err);
        return done(err);
      }

      var document = res.body;
      var entity = document.entity;

      l.logDocument(document);
      logEntity(entity);

      utest.expectSuccess(document);
      utest.expectTimeStampsOnCreate(entity, modelName);

      // Check properties are returned
      entity.should.have.property('name', 'David');
      entity.should.have.property('email', 'david@test.com');
      entity.should.have.property('role', 'orderer');
      entity.should.have.property('provider', 'local');

      //entity.should.have.property('password', 'david@test.com');
      //entity.should.not.have.property('hashedPassword');
      entity.should.not.have.property('salt');

      return done(err);
    });
```

});

**Sanitise Function**
    // THIS ENTITY HAS COME THROUGH FROM MONGOOSE.CREATE
    function santitise(entity)
    {

```
  l.kv('typeof entity', typeof entity);
  l.kv('typeof entity.salt', typeof entity.salt);

  l.line('before delete');
  l.inspect(entity);
  l.info();

  l.line('delete entity.salt');
  var isDeleted = delete entity.salt;
  l.kv('Is Successful', isDeleted);
  l.info();

  l.line('after delete');
  l.inspect(entity);

  return entity;
}
```

[image: LOG]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks JohnnyHK,

The solution was to change sanitise to the following as per: [why-cant-i-delete-a-mongoose-models-object-properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342558/why-cant-i-delete-a-mongoose-models-object-properties)

```
function sanitise(entity)
{
  var result = entity.toObject();

  delete result.hashedPassword;
  delete result.salt;

  return result;
}
```