# JavaScript's `delete` operator not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I have an object like below:

```
var doc = {
  local: {
    username: 'admin',
    status: true,
    password: '$2a$08$81Kq7/59ZASHl5k9n5cNvOUSl/HYgpLKZjs66P/OJV8vw.nHW60Ta',
    lastname: 'admin',
    firstname: 'admin',
    email: 'admin@gmail.com',
    datetime_modified: 'TueAug30201623: 10: 56GMT+0530(IST)',
    datetime_created: 'MonAug29201622: 34: 12GMT+0530(IST)'
  },
  roles: [
    'ADMIN',
    'HR'
  ],
  GridOrder: [
    {
      _id: '57e507fce94094be085425c9',
      domainName: 'items'
    }
  ],
  _id: '57c46b0c12907af910167ff5',
  __v: 9
}
```

Now I want to remove the property "GridOrder" from "doc". 
I tried using "delete" like below:

```
delete doc.GridOrder
```

and also like below:

```
delete doc['GridOrder']
```

But nothing is happening. Also I am not getting any error.

How can I remove "GridOrder" from "doc". Any ideas?

Comment: `delete doc.GridOrder` should work. Also js calls them "objects", not "hashmaps".

Comment: This works as expected when using the above code. Is it possible that a) `GridOrder` is defined using `Object.defineProperty()` or b) `GridOrder` is also a property that exists on the object's prototype chain? In both cases, `delete` will fail. *See: [delete operator - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Comment: @gfullam
I think you are right on the issue. It was defined like "a". Is there a suggestion of how to delete it?. Also can you post the above comment as an answer?

Comment: @ArunMohan Not knowing how you defined it you could do something like `Object.defineProperty(doc, 'GridOrder', {configurable: true})`, this will enable you to delete it how you were trying to do it. Check [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for more information

Comment: Best guess based on the object's contents: [Why can't I delete a mongoose model's object properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342558/why-cant-i-delete-a-mongoose-models-object-properties) Note that this is not a "pure" object, it's a Mongoose object that has custom getters and setters.

Comment: @taguenizy You cannot call `defineProperty` a second time on non-configurable properties (if `configurable` is already `false` as is the default case). In other words, `configurable` cannot be set to `true` except at the time of definition. *See : [Advanced objects in JavaScript](http://bjorn.tipling.com/advanced-objects-in-javascript)*

Comment: @gfullam what I meant is where he calls `defineProperty` he should updated it to that if possible

Answer (score 2):

## Make Object property configurable

Your minimal example works as expected when using the above code.

Based on your comment, `GridOrder` is actually being defined with [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), which by default creates non-configurable (read: non-deletable) properties.

Simply pass `configurable: true` to `Object.defineProperty` when defining the property `GridOrder`.

```js
var doc = {
  local: {
    username: 'admin',
    status: true,
    password: '$2a$08$81Kq7/59ZASHl5k9n5cNvOUSl/HYgpLKZjs66P/OJV8vw.nHW60Ta',
    lastname: 'admin',
    firstname: 'admin',
    email: 'admin@gmail.com',
    datetime_modified: 'TueAug30201623: 10: 56GMT+0530(IST)',
    datetime_created: 'MonAug29201622: 34: 12GMT+0530(IST)'
  },
  roles: [
    'ADMIN',
    'HR'
  ],
  _id: '57c46b0c12907af910167ff5',
  __v: 9
}

// Objects defined this way cannot be deleted unless `configurable` is set to `true`
Object.defineProperty(
  doc,
  'GridOrder',
  {
    configurable: true, // Defaults to `false`
    value: [
      {
        _id: '57e507fce94094be085425c9',
        domainName: 'items'
      }
    ]
  }
);

console.log('doc.GridOrder: ', doc.GridOrder);
console.log('delete doc.GridOrder: ', delete doc.GridOrder);
console.log('doc.GridOrder: ', doc.GridOrder);
```

### Caveat

> If `configurable` is `false` as is the default case, attempting to call `defineProperty` a second time will result in a JavaScript error…
>   If `configurable` is set to `true` you can modify the property again later.

[Advanced objects in JavaScript](http://bjorn.tipling.com/advanced-objects-in-javascript)

If you do not have access to the script that uses `defineProperty` to create `GridOrder`, then you will be unable to modify or delete it later.

**For example, this will fail:**

```js
/*
 * Imagine this is provided by some third-party library that you're unable to edit
 */

var doc = {};

// Objects defined this way cannot be modified or deleted because `configurable` defaults to `false`.
Object.defineProperty(
  doc,
  'GridOrder',
  {
    value: [
      {
        _id: '57e507fce94094be085425c9',
        domainName: 'items'
      }
    ]
  }
);

/*
 * Within your script…
 */

console.log('doc.GridOrder: ', doc.GridOrder);
console.log('delete doc.GridOrder: ', delete doc.GridOrder);
console.log('doc.GridOrder: ', doc.GridOrder);

// …attempts to redefine non-configurable properties will fail
Object.defineProperty(
  doc,
  'GridOrder',
  {
    configurable: true
  }
);

console.log('This will never be seen because an Error has been thrown above.');
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirm you have access to the right `object` and just use `delete`

```js
var doc = {
  local: {
    username: 'admin',
    status: true,
    password: '$2a$08$81Kq7/59ZASHl5k9n5cNvOUSl/HYgpLKZjs66P/OJV8vw.nHW60Ta',
    lastname: 'admin',
    firstname: 'admin',
    email: 'admin@gmail.com',
    datetime_modified: 'TueAug30201623: 10: 56GMT+0530(IST)',
    datetime_created: 'MonAug29201622: 34: 12GMT+0530(IST)'
  },
  roles: [
    'ADMIN',
    'HR'
  ],
  GridOrder: [
    {
      _id: '57e507fce94094be085425c9',
      domainName: 'items'
    }
  ],
  _id: '57c46b0c12907af910167ff5',
  __v: 9
}
delete doc.GridOrder;
console.log('doc.GridOrder', doc.GridOrder)
console.log(doc)
```

**EDIT**

Based on comments how you defined the property using `Object.defineProperty` you would need to add `{configurable: true}` so it's possible to `delete` as you want.

`Object.defineProperty(doc, 'GridOrder', {configurable: true})` would do it

Check reference [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: Instead of putting the "right" answer as an "EDIT", you should replace your previous answer with the new one.

Comment: @torazaburo `value` Defaults to undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You should run your code in strict mode, in which case a failed deletion will result in a run-time error, making it easier to discover:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot delete property 'foo' of #(…)`

That would also allow you to `catch` it if you really wanted to.

In sloppy mode, the `delete` operator will return false on failure, so you can check its value to help understand what's happening. According to the MDN docs:

> `true` for all cases except when the property is an own non-configurable property, in which case, `false` is returned in non-strict mode.

Note that the property merely not being present is **not** a reason for either returning `false`, or for failing of course.

One commenter claimed:

> is also a property that exists on the object's prototype chain? In both cases, delete will fail.

No, a property being on the prototype will **not** cause the `delete` to fail. It will succeed (meaning not throw, and not return `false`), but do nothing.