# Can't delete field from object returned by mongoose Model.create

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose with NodeJS. When I create new instance of a Model (called Expression), it adds the object to the database and returns me an object of the newly created model.

However.. I am unable to delete a field from this json object.

```
var savedExpr = await Expression.create(expr);
delete savedExpr["__v"]
return savedExpr;
```

This code merely returns the original savedExpr with the __v field included. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't delete some of these properties because they have been defined as ["non-configurable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342558/why-cant-i-delete-a-mongoose-models-object-properties).

```
 var savedExpr = await Expression.create(expr);
 var savedExprCopy = Object.assign({}, savedExpr);
 delete savedExprCopy["__v"];
 return savedExprCopy;

OR

 var savedExpr = await Expression.create(expr);
 savedExpr = savedExpr.toObject();
 delete savedExprCopy["__v"];
 return savedExprCopy;
```

Also an interesting thing just for knowledge,
the `__v` attribute is set to true by default, you can  disable the `__v` attribute in the Schema's definitions by setting version key option to false. 
E.g:

```
var expressionSchema = new Schema({ ... attributes ... }, { versionKey: false });
```

Comment: Rats! I was confused because [typeof savedExpr] merely returned [object]... didn't realize toObject was needed! I was thinking of turning off versionKey, but decided to leave it to be safe. Thank you for the detailed answer.