# deleting key from object but still showing in response

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, ecmascript-2016

I am experimenting with node authentication, I have managed to store a username and a hashed password into my database, but I want to return the json back without the hashed password.

I am deleting the password key before sending the JSON back but the password still shows in the returned result.

```
router.post("/signup", async (req, res, next) => {
  const user = await User.exists({ username: req.body.username });

  if (user) {
    const error = new Error("Username already exists");
    next(error);
  } else {
    const newUser = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password,
    });

    try {
      const result = await newUser.save();
      delete result.password;
      res.json(result);
    } catch (err) {
      res.json(err.errors);
    }
  }
});
```

the User model has a pre hook to hash the password before save:

```
userSchema.pre("save", async function save(next) {
  const user = this;

  if (!user.isModified("password")) return next();

  try {
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 12);
    return next();
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: I think the issue is because you define `const` instead of `let` for your result variable .

Comment: I tried that but it didnt work :(

Comment: Like that, it should works normally. If you `console.log(result)` before the `res.json(result)`, can you see that the password has been deleted? If it's the case, maybe an other route is interfering with you response body (just a guess).

Comment: If appears in the object before and after the delete

Comment: I think it is because the mongoose return object.

Comment: Here is a solution for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342558/why-cant-i-delete-a-mongoose-models-object-properties

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution thanks to Mahan for pointing it out.
`result` returns a Mongoose object so needs turning into a normal Javascript object first.

```
try {
      let result = await newUser.save();
      result = result.toObject();
      delete result.password;
      res.json(result);
    } catch (err) {
      res.json(err.errors);
    }
```